# Why do we not allow links to Google Drive files?

Tags: discussion, faq

#### This post applied not just to Google Drive but to similar file sharing platforms such as Sharepoint, Dropbox, etc.

---

- Google Drive is not accessible to all users, depending on their country of residence
- Google Drive files are almost always temporary, but we want future users to be able to click on a link and actually get the file.
- Frequently when people here have posted links to files in a Google Drive, Dropbox, or some similar type of folder, they forgot to give the public permission to view them, so we basically get dead links when we click.

#### What to do instead?

If your input or output file has fewer than about **[30,000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176445/391772)** characters then just put it in a `code` block by making a line with ``` before and after the file. For example I put **two** full input files and **two** output files (one of them full, and one of them only containing the last few lines so that I could show the essence of it) in a single question here: [Why does CCSD work, but not CCSD(T), after reading an FCIDUMP in PySCF?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10277/5)

If your file is too big (you can't fit your post in 30,000 characters), GitHub is a better alternative to Google Drive because it's meant to (or intends to) store files "permanently". Also, there's countries that banned Google but did not ban GitHub. The [Modeling Matters](https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters#readme) Git repository is a place where many input/output files associated with MMSE questions have already been posted. This is a preview of the landing page:

[image]

To add input/output files to Modeling Matters, just post your question, which will generate a URL for the question. Copy the number in the URL and make a folder with that number as the folder's name, then put your files in that folder.